# how to customize the Email sent to the user from docusign salesforce

Tags: docusign

how can i customize the email sent to the customer with  my company logo and my own custom text to the customer to view.

[image]

Javascript button :

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
var OCO='Send';
var DST = '3943779D-16CB-4EBB-8C6F-0ADC7E983A8E ';
var CEM='Dear {!Contact.FirstName},{!Contact.LastName}';
var CES='Re: Opportunity Name: {!Opportunity.Name}';
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Opportunity.Id}&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES;
```

when i am assigning the Docusign Template Id From the Portal :

I am getting the below Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you can add branding to your account. This means that you can at least change the logo and color scheme. (I did not find any way to add custom text)

This link explains how to do that: [Docusign documentation](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/branding-admin.htm)

In short: Go to your account preferences and find the topic "branding" there you can create different brands that you want to use and do some customisation.

Edit: In salesforce you can then use the id of that templateid to set the brand for the email you want to send. And even add a custom email.
For info: [docusign-for-salesforce-custom-button-logic.pdf](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-for-salesforce-custom-button-logic.pdf)

```
// DocuSign Template ID (default no template) 
DST = '67870A79-A0B5-4596-8AC1-CC7CC1EA01EB';
// Custom Email Message (default in config) 
CEM = 'Envelope sent by [FirstName] [LastName] ([Email])!'
```

The same is possible via SOAP or REST if you want to use the API. 
Look for the "createandsendenvelope" function in the documentation here:
[API Overview](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview)

Comment: Thank you for you reply .I have done what you have mentioned in your comment .Now i am looking how to customize the text sent to the customer instead of default text .

Comment: Hi Donald, I have updated my answer to explain how to customize the text.

Comment: Hi Nielsm ,please look at the question i have edited with the Error i am gettingwhen i am trying to add the Template Id using javascript button .

Comment: Hi @Donald, the error is pretty self explanatory. When you click the button docusign will look for an attachment linked to your record. This attachment (a pdf) will be used to send to your customers for signing.

On this pdf you should define (anchor)tags to indicate where the customer should sign.